# C# Windows form algorithm calculation

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm new to c# development. I have a label on the form that shows the following sequence 1,1,1,3,5,9 and a button. When the button is clicked I want it to add the sequence of numbers to the label. For example :
I know how the the above sequence works 1+1+1=3,3+1+1=5,5+3+1=9 ,so it calculates the previous 3 numbers to add to the sequence. 
What I'm trying to achieve is when the button is clicked each time it must show the next numbers that come in ex: after 9, will be 17 because 3+5+9=17 And so on... It must go up every time it's clicked .your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's very hard to determine exactly how much you have done so far. Do you have a function that takes the existing list of numbers and calculates what the new one should be? Do you know how to convert that array into a string you can show on a label? Do you know where to store the list of numbers so it's available in the button click handler and keeps its value between clicks?

Comment: Are you saying you want your algorithm to look at a series of numbers and figure out what the pattern is?  Or is the pattern always the same?

Comment: @Dylan no I don't have any function.  I  know that it will go behind the button click event. The 1,1,1,3,5,9 I just added it to the label. Not sure how to add an algorithm to calculate the next numbers.

Comment: @bj myers I want  it to figure out what the algorithm is And then calculate it. Then I must get the nth instance of the sequence where n divided by x has no remainder.

Comment: @Sarah please see the algorithm below and let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: @jamin yes something like that. But I already have these numbers 1,1,1,3,5,9 so where you added numbers.add(1),(3),(5) I should change it to numbers. Add(3),(5),(9) ? Cause I want it to display from 17 onwards. And then after that I'm not really sure what get the nth instance of a sequence where n divided by x has no remainders mean

Comment: @Sarah yes it will work no matter how many numbers you start in that List<int> so long as it's not less than 3 numbers.  See my update to the code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the algorithm you are looking to do is create a `List<int>` to contain the `int`s that are going to be used on the label.

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
```

Then you are trying to `.Add` the first 6 starting numbers into the list like so:

```
numbers.Add(1);
numbers.Add(1);
numbers.Add(1);
numbers.Add(3);
numbers.Add(5);
numbers.Add(9);
```

Once the user clicks the button, change the original label's text information to also have the result of adding the last three elements of `int` within the `List<int>`.

This can be done by using `.Count` to get the length/size of the `List<int>` in the following fashion:

```
int x = numbers[numbers.Count - 1];  //Last number/element in List
int y = numbers[numbers.Count - 2];  //Second to last
int z = numbers[numbers.Count - 3];  //Third to last
int result = x + y + z;  //sum of   last number   plus   second to last number plus   third to last   number
```

Don't forget to `.Add` the result of adding the last three elements to the end of the `List<int>`.

```
numbers.Add(result);
```

Once you have the result added, you can set the label's `.Text` value to the joining of a string in the following way:

```
numbersLabel.Text = string.Join(", ", numbers);
```

A sample demonstration of a class that contains a button, and a label that accomplishes this algorithm is below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class LabelAlgorithm : Form
    {
        public List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

        public LabelAlgorithm()
        {
            numbers.Add(1);
            numbers.Add(1);
            numbers.Add(1);
            numbers.Add(3);
            numbers.Add(5);
            numbers.Add(9);

            InitializeComponent();
            numbersLabel.Text = string.Join(", ", numbers);
        }

        private void SubmissionButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x = numbers[numbers.Count - 1];
            int y = numbers[numbers.Count - 2];
            int z = numbers[numbers.Count - 3];

            int result = x + y + z;

            numbers.Add(result);

            numbersLabel.Text = string.Join(", ", numbers);


        }
    }
}
```

Output to Label:

```
1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 31, 57, 105, 193, 355, 653, 1201, 2209, 4063...
```

Comment: Thank you,that makes sense.